# How to configure PROXY protocol in varnish upstream

Tags: proxy, varnish, proxy-protocol

I found that to accept [PROXY protocol](https://www.haproxy.org/download/1.8/doc/proxy-protocol.txt) connections in varnish all I need to do is to run varnish with extra `-a :1234,PROXY` parameter.
But what about sending those connections to upstream?

If I have following infrastructure:

```
- TLS -|- VARNISH -|- NGINX - PHP
       |           |- ...
- TLS -|- VARNISH -|- NGINX - PHP
```

How should I configure Varnish to use PROXY protocol in `Varnish -> Nginx` connection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described in https://varnish-cache.org/docs/6.0/reference/vcl.html#backend-definition, you can add a `.proxy_header` property to your backend definition to forward the PROXY protocol to your origin webserver.

Here's an example definition:

```
vcl 4.1;

backend default {
    .host = "localhost";
    .port = "8080";
    .proxy_header = 2;
}
```

This assumes Nginx is running locally on port `8080` and supports PROXY protocol v2.

While Nginx supports `listen 8080   proxy_protocol;`, I'm not sure this is part of their open source offering.

The documentation on https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/load-balancer/using-proxy-protocol/ refers to *Nginx Plus* though.